# App specific memory in lua, corona labs?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a android background now i am working in corona labs. I want to know is there any thing like preferences which we have in android. I want to manage cumulative score in my name so i was thinking if we have something like preference.

Answer (score 0):

Corona SDK uses file IO to save and load data for your app.  There is a folder called system.DocumentsDirectory that you would read and write files from.

See the sample code in the SampleCode/Storage/FileDemo/ folder for an example on how to do this.